# Detect onclicklistner fired or not for a button

Tags: android, kotlin

Now I have a `CounterDown` in the `onCreate` that generates random number on the `textView` till that every thing is fine after that I want to check the number when the user press on `textView` and another Action when he don't press on the textView. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "and another one when he don't" ? and can you explain what is a CountDown. Please write your code snippet so that it is easier to understand your question.

Comment: another action when he did not press on the textview

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.